# error when trans from layout to other layout in android

Tags: android

I want to change the black color during the short period when my app is launching but the content isn't displayed, yet.

this black color appears when trans from `splash.xml` to `activity_main.xml`, its take few min and open my App.

My StartPoint.java class is :-

```
public class StartPoint extends Activity{

ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                while(progressBarStatus < 5000){
                    StartPoint.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run()
                        {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            progressBarStatus += 1000;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, com.example.kam.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainList);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

}
```

and my splash.xml is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/loading" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.67" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity_main.xml code is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="6" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dip" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.62"
            android:background="@drawable/iconbgrepate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tileMode="repeat"
            android:weightSum="5" 
            android:alpha=".75">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/volumebar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.62"
            android:background="@drawable/iconbgrepate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tileMode="repeat"
            android:weightSum="5" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
               android:layout_width="32dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:layout_weight="0.10"
               android:background="@drawable/refreshbutton" />

           <View android:layout_weight="1" 
               android:layout_width="0dip" 
               android:layout_height="0dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPause"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:background="@drawable/pausebutton" />

            <View android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_height="0dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:background="@drawable/playbutton" />

            <View android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_height="0dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExit"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"
                android:background="@drawable/exitbutton" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and mainfest.xml is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kam.StartPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kam.MainActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

where my problem ??

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen layout is odd in that you have a weight on one of the linear layout components but not on the other.  I would add a weight sum, or provide a weight for both of them.  If you want them to consume the same amount use 1 and 1.

Also, when dealing with weights you want to have the wrap_content in the same direction (height or width).  So the design there should probably take some tweaks.  That's the first thing that I notice.

Comment: where and how can i do that, i don't understand you, i am new android development